# Gigantic database after two weeks of OpenWebAnalytics

Tags: analytics, openwebanalytics

I'm using OWA (Open Web Analytics) since 2 weeks, for a few websites, with a total of < 10k page views and < 5k visits. This is the size, in MB, of a few tables in the `owa` database:

```
| owa                | owa_session                                  |       2.80 |
| owa                | owa_request                                  |       4.44 |
| owa                | owa_click                                    |       5.30 |
| owa                | owa_domstream                                |     238.28 |
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
```

**Is it normal to have ~ 250 MB of Open Web Analytics data for only 2 weeks, for a total of < 10k page views?**

**Does this mean it will be 6.5 GB per year with the same visit rate?** Or even ~ 65 GB of analytics data for 100k page views?

Is there something wrong, or is it the right amount of magnitude?

---

*Additional informations:
According to a `mysqldump`, more than 90% of the table `owa_domstream` is wasted (or is this useful?) with:*

```
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:290},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783331,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:295},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783331,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:299},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783331,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:301},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783331,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:302},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783331,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:303},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783332,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:306},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783332,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:326},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783332,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:347},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783332,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:367},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783332,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:381},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783332,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:393},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783332,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:405},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783332,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:414},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783332,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:427},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783332,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
scroll&quot;,&quot;x&quot;:0,&quot;y&quot;:434},{&quot;timestamp&quot;:1477783332,&quot;event_type&quot;:&quot;dom.
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the OWA author, the solution is to turn off the feature

> Log Domstreams. This setting controls whether OWA should should log Domstreams.

which logs every mouse movement on every page for every visitor.
(*Admin page > General Configuration Options*).

When this feature is off, it is safe to do this in `mysql` :

```
delete from owa_domstream;
```

to bring down the size of the DB.